# How does SQL Server handle a comparison between dates when both are strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am just curious and wanted to understand how the following situation is handled by SQL Server. I am comparing two dates, but both dates are in a string format.

Let's say *date* is string, that contains a date in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Something like shown below actually works and would give me all entries with year < 2001. Are both sides cast to DATE implicitly?

```
SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE (date < '2001')
```

But when you compare *date* with an arbitrary string like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM X
WHERE (date < 'abcdefg')
```

the results don't make any sense. It does not throw an exception and if one is using '<' all the tuples are returned and if one uses '>' none of them are returned, independent of what string I put on the right side of the expression.

Secondly, I know that from a performance perspective string comparisons are very bad and that comparisons between proper date-types are much much faster. Would it be worth it to cast the entire date column to a proper format before making such a query, or does it not matter because SQL Server will make implicit casts anyways?

Could somebody explain to me how this works in the background? Thank you!

Comment: If both "dates" are strings, you are comparing strings, not dates. If you compare strings, then why do expect an error when comparing them with e.g. `< 'abcdefg'`

Comment: "*and that comparisons between proper date-types are much much faster*" - but **much** more importantly: they are _correct_. **Never**, ever store dates as strings. Just don't

Comment: If you're comparing two strings then SQL Server, and indeed most programming languages as well, doesn't do anything other than just comparing the strings according to whatever rules those comparisons follows. It certainly does **not** try to guess whether the string contains a date, a number, or whatnot else. They're strings. End of discussion.

Comment: The main question is why you're storing dates as strings if you have already realized it's a bad idea. You should convert your `date` column to a proper date type and I don't mean cast the value in your SQL, I mean change the actual type of the column so that you're in fact *storing* dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL won't do any "implicit" cast because it doesn't know that your strings are to be interpreted as dates: how could it know? So the comparison is between strings and the result will be depending on the collation you set for your DB. This usually means, digits come before letters: so, yes, "2021" is lower than any (letter based) strings